# change php error output to custom message with link

Tags: php, html, error-handling

How do I change the error output of a php error? For example if its a syntax error, or a server side time out, i want to echo a message that allows the user to refresh the page.

Heres the code I want to add my error message to:

```
$XML->registerXPathNamespace('tree','www.tree.com'); <--occasionally errors here, so I want to output my own error message.
```

Comment: You will not be able to catch syntax / fatal errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the function [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to define a custom function to be called when there is an error. You can then decide to do whatever you want within that function with the error.

If you only want it for a specific duration, you can restore it afterwards with [`restore_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.restore-error-handler.php).

```
set_error_handler('yourHandler');
...
$XML->registerXPathNamespace('tree','www.tree.com');
...
restore_error_handler();

function yourHandler(int $errno , string $errstr) {
    //show link to refresh page, whatever. full signature can be found on PHP manual page
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, quick check in php manual for [registerXPathNamespace](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) shows that it returns `TURE` or `FALSE`. Which is perfect for my solution.

```
if (!@$XML->registerXPathNamespace('tree','www.tree.com')) {
    echo '<b>ERROR:</b> Could not register xml path. Please reload the page!';
}
```

Not that, if it returns FALSE, then the message will be displayed. And the `@` in front of $XML will disable the original errors that, that action may cause.

Comment: Errors are there for a good reason, better to switch them on/off on a per-vhost-base instead directly inside the code. This would give you the ability to have a test- and a production-server.

Comment: @feeela My solution for xml related errors, that can occur, is perfect. This doesn't display the errors for that certain call and you don't have to mess with your ini_set and similar core-settings. Because errors/messages are there for a reason, however there are cases like xml related functions, where you must have the ability to turn them off.

Comment: @feeela Actually I think your comment is irrelevant to my answer and doesn't explain the downvote. This method doesn't need to turn off errors complete, it does it only on the single call.. This is the fastest method in the performance term..